# Display japanese string in qt and qml

Tags: qt, qml, qstring

I have a QString which contains a japanese string. But while debugging its just showing "???" in place of string. I need it to display it in qml. I have used QtextCodec but didnt work for me. Please give any solution or suggestion to fix the issue.

Comment: Which encoding is your source code in: UTF-8, UTF-16, something else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
label->setText(QString::fromLocal8Bit("日本語"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Save source file in UTF-8 (or other which can encode your characters) encoding
2. Set default codec with `QtextCodec` (I've tried, and it is working without this setting, too).
3. Use `label->setText(QString::fromWCharArray(L"日本語"));`